# XPath selector based on element above

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath

I'm not sure if my request is even possible, but since Wordpress XML export is a mess I need to find a way of getting what I need. Here is some example XML output that I have.

```
<xml>
  <wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[108]]></wp:meta_value>
  </wp:postmeta>
  <wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key>_aioseop_keywords</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[keyword1, keyword2]]>
  </wp:meta_value>
</xml>
```

Now I am trying to get the value of keywords, I have tried to use an exact path selector but the problem is sometimes the keyword element area may sit above the _thumbnail_id.

I want to get the value of 'wp:meta_value' based on 'wp:meta_key' value being equal to '_aioseop_keywords'.

How can this be achieved, the other less favourable alternative is how to get Wordpress to properly extract decent XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath

```
/xml/wp:postmeta[wp:meta_key = '_aioseop_keywords']/wp:meta_value
```

will give you the

> value of 'wp:meta_value' based on 'wp:meta_key'
> value being equal to '_aioseop_keywords'.

for the XML you provided.  Be sure to [register the namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085).

Comment: Awesome, that worked exactly as i needed it to. Do you know of any documentation for it so i can fully understand the logic and similar selectors. Have looked but cannot find it.

Comment: You can learn a lot from the examples given in the [Location Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) section of the XPath Recommendation.