# How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

**How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?**

If I use

```
/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/Id
```

to parse the XML document below I get 0 nodes back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" 
                time="2016-10-14T10:48:39.109-07:00">
    <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="79" totalCount="79">
        <Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Id>=1</Id>
        </Bill>
    </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

However, I'm not specifying the namespace in the XPath (i.e. `http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3` is not a prefix of each token of the path). How can XPath know which `Id` I want if I don't tell it explicitly? I suppose in this case (since there is only one namespace) XPath could get away with ignoring the `xmlns` entirely. But if there are multiple namespaces, things could get ugly.

Comment: Your XPath should not return any node : [INFO - XPath returned 0 items (compiled in 0ms, evaluated in 1ms)](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/db27cc0f978057b5faabc32c6aa149c8). How did you execute the XPath?

Comment: @har07 I did it in Java using import `javax.xml.xpath.XPath`. I agree it doesn't work using an online tester. That was one of the perplexing things.

Comment: Excellent question!  XPath itself provides no way to specify a default namespace or the binding of a namespace prefix to a namespace.  Fortunately, however, hosting languages and libraries do.  [**See my answer below for details**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/290085)...

Comment: Not quite sure why a question should be upvoted so highly when it has been asked and answered 1000 times before....

Comment: I for one was impressed with this question because, unlike most previous askers, Adam not only included a [mcve], he sensed and conveyed the need for XPath to deal with XML namespaces *somehow*.  Most such questions merely post an XPath, maybe some XML (and if we're lucky it's not an image or a link to a humongous off-site resource), and state that it "doesn't work."  Adam sensed it had to do with namespaces, nailed the title, and wrote what I considered to be a question worthy of a  canonical answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query XML using namespaces in Java with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## XPath 1.0/2.0

### Defining namespaces in XPath <sub><sup>(recommended)</sup></sub>

XPath itself doesn't have a way to bind a namespace prefix with a namespace.  Such facilities are provided by the hosting library.

It is recommended that you use those facilities and define namespace prefixes that can then be used to qualify XML element and attribute names as necessary.

---

Here are some of the various mechanisms which XPath hosts provide for specifying namespace prefix bindings to namespace URIs.

<sup><sub>(OP's original XPath, `/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/Id`, has been elided to `/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse`.)</sub></sup>

**C#:**

```cs
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3");
XmlNodeList nodes = el.SelectNodes(@"/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse", nsmgr);
```

**Google Docs:**

Unfortunately, [`IMPORTXML()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) does not provide a namespace prefix binding mechanism.  See next section, **Defeating namespaces in XPath**, for how to use `local-name()` as a work-around.

**Java (SAX):**

```java
NamespaceSupport support = new NamespaceSupport();
support.pushContext();
support.declarePrefix("i", "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3");
```

**Java (XPath):**

```java
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
      switch (prefix) {
        case "i": return "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3";
        // ...
       }
    });
```

- Remember to call
  [`DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29).
- See also:
  [Java XPath: Queries with default namespace xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720452/java-xpath-queries-with-default-namespace-xmlns)

**JavaScript:**

See [Implementing a User Defined Namespace Resolver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver):

```js
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    'i' : 'http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
document.evaluate( '/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse', 
                   document, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, 
                   null );
```

Note that if the default namespace has an associated namespace prefix defined, using the `nsResolver()` returned by [`Document.createNSResolver()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNSResolver) can obviate the need for a customer `nsResolver()`.

**Perl ([LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod)):**

```perl
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
$xc->registerNs('i', 'http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3');
my @nodes = $xc->findnodes('/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse');
```

**Python ([lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes)):**

```python
from lxml import etree
f = StringIO('<IntuitResponse>...</IntuitResponse>')
doc = etree.parse(f)
r = doc.xpath('/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse', 
              namespaces={'i':'http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3'})
```

**Python ([ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14853243/290085)):**

```python
namespaces = {'i': 'http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3'}
root.findall('/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse', namespaces)
```

**Python ([Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html)):**

```python
response.selector.register_namespace('i', 'http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3')
response.xpath('/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse').getall()
```

**PhP:**

Adapted from [@Tomalak's answer using DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475568/290085):

```php
$result = new DOMDocument();
$result->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($result);
$xpath->registerNamespace("i", "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3");

$result = $xpath->query("/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse");
```

See also [@IMSoP's canonical Q/A on PHP SimpleXML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/290085).

**Ruby (Nokogiri):**

```rb
puts doc.xpath('/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse',
                'i' => "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3")
```

Note that Nokogiri supports removal of namespaces,

```rb
doc.remove_namespaces!
```

but see the below warnings discouraging the defeating of XML namespaces.

**VBA:**

```vba
xmlNS = "xmlns:i='http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3'"
doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNS  
Set queryResponseElement =doc.SelectSingleNode("/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse")
```

**VB.NET:**

```vb
xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load("file.xml")
nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(New XmlNameTable())
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3");
nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse",
                                           nsmgr)
```

**SoapUI ([doc](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/validating-xml-messages/)):**

```
declare namespace i='http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3';
/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse
```

**xmlstarlet:**

```sh
-N i="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3"
```

**XSLT:**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:i="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   ...
```

---

Once you've declared a namespace prefix, your XPath can be written to use it:

```
/i:IntuitResponse/i:QueryResponse
```

---

### Defeating namespaces in XPath <sub><sup>(not recommended)</sup></sub>

An alternative is to write predicates that test against `local-name()`:

```
/*[local-name()='IntuitResponse']/*[local-name()='QueryResponse']
```

Or, in XPath 2.0:

```
/*:IntuitResponse/*:QueryResponse
```

Skirting namespaces in this manner works but is not recommended because it

- Under-specifies the full element/attribute name.
- Fails to differentiate between element/attribute names in different
  namespaces (the very purpose of namespaces).  Note that this concern could be addressed by adding an additional predicate to check the namespace URI explicitly:

  ```
   /*[    namespace-uri()='http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3' 
      and local-name()='IntuitResponse']
   /*[    namespace-uri()='http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3' 
      and local-name()='QueryResponse']
  ```

  <sub>Thanks to [Daniel Haley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317052/daniel-haley) for the `namespace-uri()` note.</sub>
- Is excessively verbose.

## XPath 3.0/3.1

Libraries and tools that support modern XPath 3.0/3.1 allow the specification of a namespace URI directly in an XPath expression:

```
/Q{http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3}IntuitResponse/Q{http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3}QueryResponse
```

While `Q{http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3}` is much more verbose than using an XML namespace prefix, it has the advantage of being independent of the namespace prefix binding mechanism of the hosting library.  The `Q{}` notation is known as *Clark Notation* after its originator, James Clark.  The W3C XPath 3.1 EBNF grammar calls it a [`BracedURILiteral`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#prod-xpath31-BracedURILiteral).

<sub>Thanks to [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) for the suggestion to cover XPath 3.0/3.1's `BracedURILiteral`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. One thing I still don't understand though is how when I use a library like Javax or Pugi XML to parse the XML above with the path I specified, I actually do get results (i.e. a node list) back. Do some of these libraries have an ability to somehow infer simple namespaces?

Comment: I think what it's doing is just ignoring namespaces entirely. If I use `/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/Id` without registering a namespace, pugi/javax retrieve *all* `Id`s in the document.

Comment: Is this the same pugixml that states in its 1.8 manual, [8.6. Conformance to W3C specification](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#xpath.w3c), that it *does not provide a fully conformant XPath 1.0 implementation*?  If so, that would explain the behavior you're seeing, and, if so, I would recommend avoiding it and all other non-conformant processors.

Comment: I couldn't see anything is that section that fully explains why it would retrieve all `Id`s when namespace isn't specified. Am I missing something, or should I just chalk the behaviour up to "pugi is not fully conformant to the W3C specs and so does weird stuff sometimes". But that doesn't explain why when using the Javax library for XPath I get the same behaviour.

Comment: pugi: nonconformance declaration in docs + odd behavior observation = turn and run / life's too short.   Javax: Don't forget to call [**`setNamespaceAware(true)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29) on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Comment: Turns out pugixml doesn't support xml namespaces at all (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/using-boost-to-read-and-write-xml-files). Turning and running.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: Gem of an answer.

Comment: damn fine answer sir. i would add, if you want to use xpath axis (at least with `lxml`) you can just insert it before the element name like `root.xpath("child::foo:element", namepsace={"foo": "bar"})` this is not documented in the `lxml` docs.

Comment: It might be worth adding that in XPath 3.0/3.1, instead of using `foo:element` and defining a binding for `foo` in the external API, you can write `Q{http://example.com/ns}element` which avoids use of namespace prefixes entirely. This is most useful when the extra verbosity doesn't matter, for example if the XPath code is software-generated.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Good idea!  Answer updated to describe XPath 3.0/3.1's new `BracedURILiteral` syntax.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I use `/*[name()='...']` in a google sheet to fetch some counts from Wikidata. I have a table like this

```
 thes    WD prop links   items
 NOM     P7749   3925    3789
 AAT     P1014   21157   20224
```

and the formulas in cols `links` and `items` are

```
=IMPORTXML("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT(COUNT(*)as?c){?item wdt:"&$B14&"[]}","//*[name()='literal']")
=IMPORTXML("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT(COUNT(distinct?item)as?c){?item wdt:"&$B14&"[]}","//*[name()='literal']")
```

respectively. The SPARQL query happens not to have any spaces...

I saw `name()` used instead of `local-name()` in [Xml Namespace breaking my xpath!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath), and for some reason `//*:literal` doesn't work.