# How to read nodes in XSD document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

> I've the below xsd file. I am trying to append few tag. However traversing with xsd schema can be one of the possible solution. Here I just want to append few nodes like.

```
  <xs:element name="Prefix" type="xs:string"/> TO
  <xs:element name="Prefix" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" />
  <xs:element name="EventReasonCode" type="xs:string"/> TO
  <xs:element name="EventReasonCode" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" />
```

> Full XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"  xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/MergePatient.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/MergePatient/MergePatient.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MergePatient.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="http://tempuri.org/MergePatient/MergePatient/MergePatient.xsd" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/MergePatient/MergePatient/MergePatient.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" id="MergePatient">
   <xs:element name="MergePatient">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="PatientName" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="MiddleName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Prefix" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="EventReasonCode" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

> Tried So far

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("file.XSD");
            XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList xNodes1 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//xs:element[xs:complexType/xs:sequence]");
```

Unable to read the tag with the path above.

Comment: @kjhughes Could you add the reference of this question?

Comment: Do you mean the duplicate link?  It's already there:  [**How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)   (Your particular problem is that you've not defined the `xs` namespace prefix before using it in your XPath; see the duplicate link for more details.)

Comment: @kjhughes I am trying to read node, but the collection is empty.   XmlNodeList xNodes1 = root.SelectNodes(@"/xs:schema/xs:annotation", manager);

Comment: Did you define the `xs` namespace prefix before using it?

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, It's defined. Plse see the piece of code in my question

Comment: I guess namespace url should be "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Comment: @kjhughes  Your answer in the other links seems to just read the particular node, string manipulation seems difficult here.

Comment: String manipulation would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @kjhughes. Well my question was that. Kindly remove the duplicate flag as your other link doesn't answer my question

Comment: **Rollback explanation:**  Your edit fundamentally altered the nature of the question.   Please ask a new question instead.   Having a rolling series of ongoing corrections within the same question is not appropriate for this site.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes. I agree. But I guess you just checked my question's heading and didn't read the content. This was the reason you marked the duplicate flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129625/discussion-between-vivek-ranjan-and-kjhughes).

Comment: I read your entire question.  You asked why `xNodes1` was empty.  Duplicate addressed that.   Ask new question for your additional problems -- don't just string along a series of edits to this question.  Thanks.