# XPath select based on child value(s)

Tags: xml, xpath

Here's some xml:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Tom</author>
        <genres>
            <genre>Science</genre>
            <genre>Romance</genre>
        </genres>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Mike</author>
        <genres>
            <genre>Politics</genre>
            <genre>Romance</genre>
        </genres>
    </book>
</books>
```

How can I define an xpath such that it pulls all Romance books? Or maybe all Romance and Politics books?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can go with `//book[./genres/genre = 'Romance']` and `//book[./genres/genre = 'Romance' and ./genres/genre = 'Politics']`, respectively

Comment: I actually tried this exactly but it didn't return results.   I am probably missing something somewhere.  I'll play some more.

Comment: @jglazer Does your actual XML document look exactly like the one you show above, or did you perhaps omit something or simplify it? Rubens, `./` in the predicates is not necessary, `child::` is implicitly assumed as the context.

Comment: @jglazer: This answer is correct (+1), only slightly more verbose than necessary (as Mathias mentioned).  I've added some [**XPath troubleshooting steps**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41030788/290085) to my answer  -- hopefully those will help.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes etc....  I Won't be able to play with it until next week but I'll give it more effort.

Answer (score 10):

*All books in Romance genre*:

```
//book[genres/genre = 'Romance']
```

*All books in Romance **and** Politics genre*:

```
//book[genres/genre = 'Romance' and genres/genre = 'Politics']
```

*All books in Romance **that are also in** Politics genre (same as `and` above)*:

```
//book[genres/genre = 'Romance'][genres/genre = 'Politics']
```

*All books in Romance **or** Politics genre*:

```
//book[genres/genre = 'Romance' or genres/genre = 'Politics']
```

*All books in Romance **or** Politics genre*  (XPath 2.0 only):

```
//book[genres/genre = ('Romance', 'Politics')]
```

---

**Notes:**

1. `//book` finds all `book` elements anywhere beneath the root
   element; `/books/book` finds all `book` children of the `books` root
   element.  For the given XML, they select the same elements.
2. You can append `/author` to any of the above XPaths to select the
   `author` elements of the books of the specified criteria.

---

### Having trouble making it work?

**First**, establish that a basic XPath works:  `//book` should return two elements.

If it does not:

1. Check spelling carefully of both the XPath expression and the XML.
2. Check case.  XML and XPath are case sensitive.
3. Check that no namespaces are in play.  Namespaces are effectively a
   part of the names of elements and attributes and must be accounted
   for.  See
   [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

**Then**, incrementally add XPath steps from there:

1. `//book[genres]` should select `book` elements with any `genres`
   child element.
2. `//book[genres/genre]` should select `book` elements with any
   `genres` child element, only if it in turn has a `genre` child
   element.
3. `//book[genres/genre = 'Romance']` should select *all books in
   Romance genre*, as requested.  Note that `'Romance'` must be quoted;
   otherwise, the expression would be testing against the string value
   of a `Romance` child element of `book` and will certainly fail.