# Why is this xpath returning an empty nodeset?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**Here is the XML:**

```
    <recordTarget>
        <patientRole>
          <patient>
           <religiousAffiliationCode code="1013" displayName="Christian (non-Catholic, non-specific)" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1076" codeSystemName="HL7 Religious Affiliation"/>
   </patient>
</patientRole>
</recordTarget>
```

**Here is my xpath statement (n1 is namespace)**

```
<xsl:variable name="religion" select="n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:patient/n1:religiousAffilliationCode/@displayName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of evaluating your XPath against your XML depends upon factors you've not told us.

It is dependent upon

- the current context since it is a relative
  XPath.
- the definition of the `n1` namespace prefix
  being consistently defined in the XML and in the language hosting the
  XPath.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)
- the namespace of `recordTarget`, `patientRole`,
  etc, which cannot be determined without seeing their full heritage.

Comment: I only included a small amount of the XML, but current context is correct, namespace n1 is defined. Michael Kay has a sharp eye. It is a spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of `religiousAffiliationCode`.

(Incidentally, the only real defence against spelling mistakes in path expressions is to use the schema-awareness features in XSLT 2.0, which if you take advantage of them correctly give you compile-time checking that the paths make sense with respect to the schema. This is particularly relevant when using a vocabulary like HL7 where the names tend to be long and tortuous.)

Comment: You have a sharp eye my friend. Thanks!