# xmlstarlet select sibling based on text value

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I've been trying to get through this with different options and couldn't find the correct way of doing it.
Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
        <members>PriceRule__c.All</members>
        <members>PriceRule__c.None</members>
        <members>ProductRule__c.All</members>
        <members>Quote__c.All_Quotes</members>
        <members>SummaryVariable__c.All</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
  </types>
  <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AnalyticSnapshot</name>
  </types>
</Package>
```

I want to be able to get the text of the "name" node that is in the same "types" node for any "members" node that starts with PriceRule__c.
Here is the furthest I could get which was to actually find the values of those nodes:

```
echo $(xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -v "//x:types/*[starts-with(text(),'PriceRule__c')]" test.xml)
```

This prints out:

```
PriceRule__c.All PriceRule__c.None
```

But what I need is a way to get the value **ListView**
Any idea how the XPath should be to get that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your XPath to

```
//x:types[starts-with(x:members,'PriceRule__c')]/x:name
```

and you will select the `x:name` with value, `ListView`, as requested.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the "x:" is for/represents in the example.

Comment: @BillHileman: It is a namespace prefix, defined by OP via `-N` in xmlstarlet to cover the default namespace in the XML document.  See [***How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)