# lxml xpath returns an empty list

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="pc chrome win psc_dir-ltr psc_form-xlarge" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<title>Some Title</title>
</html>
```

if I run:

```
from lxml import etree
html = etree.parse('text.txt')
result = html.xpath('//title')
print(result)
```

I will get an empty list.
I guess it has something to do with namespace, but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using the xml or html tree builder? http://lxml.de/parsing.html

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the tree using the html parser. 
Also note that if `text.txt` is a file it will need to be read first.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text_html = f.read()
```

like this:

```
from lxml import etree, html

def build_lxml_tree(_html):
    tree = html.fromstring(_html)
    tree = etree.ElementTree(tree)
    return tree

tree = build_lxml_tree(text_html)
result = tree.xpath('//title')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the HTML parser :

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser() 
html = etree.parse('text.txt',parser)
result = html.xpath('//title')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can do like this:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser() 
html = etree.parse('text.txt',parser)
result = html.xpath('//title/text()')
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
['Some Title']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `namespaces` parameter of the `xpath` method like this:

```
from lxml import etree
html = etree.parse('text.txt')
result = html.xpath('//n:title', namespaces = {'n': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
```

According to the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) "[...] XPath does not have a notion of a default namespace. The empty prefix is therefore undefined for XPath and cannot be used in namespace prefix mappings", so if you are working with an element that has a default namespace you can explicitly define the namespace when calling `xpath`.

For more information see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/16342964) with a great answer.