# Xpath function to find out string length of an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml message body as below. I need to find out if string length of the attribute 'SenderId' is greater than 0. I am unable to find this.

XML Message

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Audit xmlns="http://schemas.Auditlog.xsd">
<MessageId>1234</MessageId>
<SenderDetails CreatedDate="2017-Jan-12" SenderId="App1"/>
</Audit>
```

I am using below xpath function to get the string length of SenderId

```
when(xpath("string-length(string(//node()[local-name()='SenderDetails']/@[local-name()='SenderId']/text()))>0))
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What is the environment you use to execute the XPath, i.e. what is the host programming language/DOM API?

Comment: it is spring based project, programming in Java DSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
string-length(//*[local-name() = 'SenderDetails']/@SenderId)
```

will return 4 because the attribute value of `@SenderId` is `App1`, which has a string length of 4.  You can test its return value by appending `> 0` if you wish to return true for positive numbers.

See **[How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)** to learn how to declare and use a namespace prefix in your XPath, which is preferable to defeating namespaces via `local-name()`.