# XPath and Namespace

Tags: xpath, namespaces

I have the following soap response and want to extract the list of products:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <listProductsResponse xmlns="http://warehouse.acme.com/ws">
         <listProductsResult>
            <listProductsResult>
               <productName>hammer</productName>
               <productId>54112</productId>
            </listProductsResult>
            <listProductsResult>
               <productName>drill</productName>
               <productId>54113</productId>
            </listProductsResult>
            <listProductsResult>
               <productName>circular saw</productName>
               <productId>54114</productId>
            </listProductsResult>
            <listProductsResult>
               <productName>jigsaw</productName>
               <productId>54115</productId>
            </listProductsResult>
         </listProductsResult>
      </listProductsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The following XPath returns a "No Match". I'm wondering why?

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:listProductsResponse
```

The following is working but seems to me a dirty approach since a namespace is specified for listProductsResponse:

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*[local-name()="listProductsResponse"]
```

Comment: Which xpath engine you are using, you need to tell that to be aware of the namespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)

Comment: @svasa Thanks - I was testing with https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester first.