# Xpath Search for Element Regardless of Attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an an xpath

```
//ServiceDefinition/schema/sequenceType[@name="Data"]/element/@name'))
```

That works great with xml

```
<ServiceDefinition>
   <schema>
      .....
   </schema>
</ServiceDefintion>
```

The issue is the first line of xml file really is

```
  <ServiceDefinition xmlns="http:/schemas/api" name="thename" version="1.0.0.45">
```

The above xpath returns empty when I include those 3 attributes.  Is there a way to modify the xpath so look for this ServiceDefinition element but does not care about the attributes?  I know I can specify values for the 3 attributes but at least the version will change. I know I can wildcard the values but could not figure a way to just inspect the attributes at all

Comment: I think you are right..  Is this effectivly saying that reason for no match is not that  I have those xml attributes but that one is specifically one that defines the name space?

Comment: Yes, it's specifically the `xmlns` attribute that is bugging you. Any other attribute is fine.

Comment: You can either register the namespace (method depends on hosting language) or you can bypass them (not recommended).  See [*my answer to How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/290085) for a thorough explanation of your options either way (for many different hosting languages too).

Comment: if you are using DOM, just turn off namespace awreness... not hard at all...

Comment: I did this to support the namespace

`my $filename = '/home/myfile.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);`


my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('ns',  'http://schemas/apidd');


foreach my $title ($xpc->findnodes('//ns:ServiceDefinition/schema')) {
 say $title->to_literal();
 };

What is weird is my xpath is behaving a bit different  ns:ServiceDefinitionn returns data but when I start to build out the xpath further it fails.  

does using the name space return additional changes to the xpath?

Comment: If I wanted to turn off namespace awareness, how does one do that? @vtd-xml-author

Comment: I was able to address the above smaller issue be adjusting findnodes to have ns in front of each node.