# Using XPath, how are attributes that contain a colon character processed?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Given the following XML (fragment):

```
<node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f598" type="Group" ext:score="90">
<node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f599" type="Person" ext:score="100">
<node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f600" type="Business" ext:score="80">
```

I want to retrieve the `id` of nodes that have an `ext:score` of 100.

The current code:

```
match = dom.xpath('//node[@ext:score="100"]/@id')[0]
```

Returns an exception:

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

I have read (both here and in XPath docs) that `ext` would first need to be defined as a valid namespace, as the DOM cannot be parsed as an attribute if it contains *special* characters.  However, I have been unable to find a good example of how to do this.  There is no definition of `ext` in the excerpts I am processing and I'm not sure how to create a namespace `prefix`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)

Comment: I've read that @kjhughes, and I understand how to *create* a namespace, but I don't see how I can then use that namespace prefix to test for a condition.  Still looking... Thanks!

Comment: Does your XML have a namespace declaration for `ext` -- something like `xmlns:ext="http://example.com/extention"` on an element above the `node` elements?

Comment: @kjhughes - I don't (these come to me *as-is*,) but I've been told that the original contains this: `<metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" created="2017-11-16T12:09:30.334Z">` which is what I used to try to *synthesize* the prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon character in an XML attribute (or element) name such as `ext:score` separates the namespace prefix, `ext`, from the local name, `score`.  Namespace prefixes themselves are significant only by virtue of their association with a namespace value.

For this XML,

```
<metadata xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#">
  <node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f598" type="Group" ext:score="90">
  <node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f599" type="Person" ext:score="100">
  <node id="b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f600" type="Business" ext:score="80">
</metadata>
```

This XPath,

```
//node[@ext:score="100"]/@id
```

will select the `id` attributes of all `node` elements with an `ext:score` attribute value of `100`, *provided you have a way to bind a namespace prefix (`ext`) to a namespace value (`http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#` in the language or tool from which XPath is being called.*

To bind a namespace prefix to a namespace value in Python (see [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085) for Python and other language examples):

```
from lxml import etree
f = StringIO('your XML here')
doc = etree.parse(f)
r = doc.xpath('//node[@ext:score="100"]/@id', 
              namespaces={'ext':'http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0'})
```

Note that if your XML uses `ext` without declaring it, it is not [***namespace-well-formed***.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)

Comment: Working perfectly now - much appreciated @kjhughes