# Xpath compilation for Child element with namespace + Getting error - Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns2

Tags: dom, xpath, namespaces, xpath-2.0

**Sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<ns2:bookStore xmlns:ns2="http://bookstore.com/schemes">
    <ns2:book id="1">
        <ns2:name>Data Structure</ns2:name>
    </ns2:book>
    <ns2:book id="2">
        <ns2:name>Java Core</ns2:name>
    </ns2:book>
</ns2:bookStore>
</Root>
```

**Java code**

```
XPathExpression expr = 
xpath.compile("//Root/ns2:bookStore/ns2:book/ns2:name/text()");
```

I get ***Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ns2*** error with above xml with **Root**

tag. By removing the **Root** tag I'm able to parse the data. Any help would be appreciated without modifying the XML file.

Comment: Duplicate of [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)   (You have to call `xpath.setNamespaceContext()`. )

Comment: I do call xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(doc)); with source document for the lookup  sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a full [mcve].  Omitting key code relating to namespace prefix resolution will impede our ability to help you. Thanks.