# How to specify Xpath location for following xml?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using xmlsec to parse an xml to generate xml signature. And after reading wikipedia page on XPath, I tried to sign following sample xml file.

My xml looks like this:

```
<References>
    <env:Envelope>
        <book:Book xml:id="BookBSchneier">
                <tns:search>
                </tns:search>
                <audit:user >
                </audit:user>
        </book:Book>
  </env:Envelope>
</References>
```

I have given xpath like this:

> /child::References/child::env:Envelope/child::book:Book/child::audit:user

But it is giving error:

> XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix XPath error : Invalid
>   expression

Comment: If you use a namespace-prefix in an XPath expression, you must define what namespace to bind to the prefix and register it with the engine executing the XPath. What are the namespace for the `env`, `book`, and `audit` namespace-prefixes? Your example XML is not valid. Those elements don't have namespaces for those prefixes either.

Comment: First make your XML [***namespace-well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) by declaring the namespace prefixes in use, as @MadsHansen recommends.  Then see the duplicate link for [**how to use XPath with namespaces**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085).