# Extract values conditionally from namespaced XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I need to extract some info from a XML using XPath ... the XML is like the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" >
   <title type="text">DataEntities</title>
   <m:count>4</m:count>
   <entry>
      <id>0001</id>
      <title type="text">DataEntities</title>
      <content type="application/xml">
         <m:properties>
            <d:internalId>5b1daf597f3aee4f0d93e1ed</d:internalId>
            <d:datasetVersion>2</d:datasetVersion>
            <d:Product>PRODUCT0001</d:Product>
            <d:Version>6.0.0</d:Version>
            <d:Middleware>Apache WebServer</d:Middleware>
            <d:Versionmiddleware>2.2.31</d:Versionmiddleware>
            <d:Hostname>server01.mydomain.com</d:Hostname>
            <d:Technology>PHP</d:Technology>
         </m:properties>
      </content>
   </entry>
   <entry>
     <id>0002</id>
     <title type="text">DataEntities</title>
     <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
           <d:internalId>5b1daf345f3aee4f0d34e1ed</d:internalId>
           <d:datasetVersion>2</d:datasetVersion>
           <d:Product>PRODUCT0002</d:Product>
           <d:Version>1.0.0</d:Version>
           <d:Middleware>Apache WebServer</d:Middleware>
           <d:Versionmiddleware>2.2.31</d:Versionmiddleware>
           <d:Hostname>server02.mydomain.com</d:Hostname>
           <d:Technology>Java</d:Technology>
        </m:properties>
     </content>
   </entry>
   <entry>
     <id>0003</id>
     <title type="text">DataEntities</title>
     <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
           <d:internalId>5b1daf123f3aee4f0d33e1ed</d:internalId>
           <d:datasetVersion>2</d:datasetVersion>
           <d:Product>PRODUCT0003</d:Product>
           <d:Version>5.0.0</d:Version>
           <d:Middleware>Apache WebServer</d:Middleware>
           <d:Versionmiddleware>2.2.31</d:Versionmiddleware>
           <d:Hostname>server01.mydomain.com</d:Hostname>
           <d:Technology>PHP</d:Technology>
        </m:properties>
     </content>
   </entry>
   <entry>
     <id>0004</id>
     <title type="text">DataEntities</title>
     <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
           <d:internalId>5b1daf345f3aee4f0d34e1ed</d:internalId>
           <d:datasetVersion>2</d:datasetVersion>
           <d:Product>PRODUCT0004</d:Product>
           <d:Version>4.0.0</d:Version>
           <d:Middleware>Apache WebServer</d:Middleware>
           <d:Versionmiddleware>2.2.31</d:Versionmiddleware>
           <d:Hostname>server01.mydomain.com</d:Hostname>
           <d:Technology>PHP</d:Technology>
        </m:properties>
     </content>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

**What I need is to find the products that are on the same hostname,** for example fixing the server like "server01.mydomain.com" to extract, as result, PRODUCT0001, PRODUCT0003 and PRODUCT0004 (note NOT PRODUCT0002), or, fixing the server like "server02.mydomain.com" to extract , as result, only PRODUCT0002.

I've tried to use

```
//d:Product
```

and it works and the result is

```
Element='<d:Product xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">PRODUCT0001</d:Product>'
Element='<d:Product xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">PRODUCT0002</d:Product>'
Element='<d:Product xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">PRODUCT0003</d:Product>'
Element='<d:Product xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">PRODUCT0004</d:Product>'
```

I don't know how to indicate that I need "only" the products that are on the `d:Hostname` value "server01.mydomain.com"

I've tried using

```
//d:Product/@d:Hostname['server01.mydomain.com']
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions about the XPath syntax I have to use?

Comment: I've added some little details in my original question .... sorry but I'm quite a newbye about Xpath ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've [properly bound the namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085) as declared in your XML to your XPath library, this XPath,

```
//m:properties[d:Hostname="server01.mydomain.com"]/d:Product
```

will return those `d:Product` elements in `m:properties` with `d:Hostname` string value equal to `"server01.mydomain.com"`, as requested.