# XPath function ends-with is throwing exception where as starts-with working fine

Tags: xpath

I am trying to use X Path function "ends-with(Name,'A')"
but i get the following exception
"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Kindly let me know how to make it work in C# , I using Xpath Navigator compile function to get the output.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `starts-with()` vs `ends-with()` but rather with how to use namespaces in XPath.  See duplicate link for help there.  Also, provide a [mcve] in the future if you want specific help with a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the duplicate link here

Comment: I already have.  It is in the yellow area below the words, **This question already has an answer here:** [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces)