# I am looking to check values in xml using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<myRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:ben”>
  <myDefinition>
    <name>Value1</name>
    <version>Value2</version>
  </myDefinition>
  <myHeader>
    <id>52452519-4765-4b68-b632-01913c3d3948</id>
    <creationTime>2018-07-04T10:51:56</creationTime>
    <target>
      <myCode>value3</myCode>
    </target>
  </myHeader>
</myRequest>
```

I am looking to check the text between name element is 'Value1', text between version is 'Value2' and text between myCode is 'Value3'.

How can I check these values in a single xpath query?

Comment: What do you mean by *"check values"*? Share your current XPath and desired output

Comment: So I have an element <name>Value1</name> and I want to assert that "Value1" is the text between the name tags. In the same query I also want to check "value3" is between the follow element <myCode>value3</myCode> etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select `myRequest` that meet following requirements:

- contains `name` descendant with text `"Value1"`
- contains `version` descendant with text `"Value2"`
- contains `mycode` descendant with text `"Value3"`

try below XPath:

```
/myRequest[myDefinition[name="Value1" and version="Value2"] and myHeader[target/myCode="Value3"]]
```

Comment: @Benl2 , any feedback?

Comment: Good (+1), but OP will also have to fix the closing script quote in the XML (has to be normal double quote) and then account for the default namespace: 
 `xmlns="urn:ben”`.  See [***How does XPath deal with namespaces?***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)