# XPath select multiple nodes using a single path

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon, xforms

Let's say I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<Users>
  <User>Bob</User>
  <User>Stefania</User>
</Users>
```

If I wanted to select line 3, one of the ways I could do it like this using local-name():

```
//*[local-name()='Users']/*[local-name()='User'][1]
```

My question is this. Is it possible to select multiple nodes using one statement? I've tried:

```
//*[local-name()='Users/User'][1]
```

In reality, the strings would be replaced with variables. In XForms a real example would look like this:

```
<xf:var name="users" value="'Users"/>
<xf:var name="user" value="'User"/>
<xf:setvalue ref="//*[local-name()=$users/$user][1]" value="'Jim'"/>
```

But that doesn't work.

What I'd like to be able to do it something like this:

```
<xf:var name="users" value="'Users"/>
<xf:var name="user" value="'User"/>
<xf:var name="myPath" value="'$users/$user'"/>
<xf:setvalue ref="//*[local-name()=$myPath][1]" value="'Jim'"/>
```

Comment: By "selecting multiple nodes", you mean you want to select both `<User>Bob</User>` and `<User>Stefania</User>`?

Comment: Nope, I mean multiple nodes in a single path. (Not 100% node is the correct terminology). See the example I just added at the end.

Comment: The short answer is *no*, you cannot write `//*[local-name()=$users/$user]` instead of `//*[local-name()=$users]/*[local-name()=$user]`. Are you just trying to find a shorter syntax, or is there something more to it?

Comment: @avernet No, there’s nothing more to it other than to find a shorter syntax. Thank you. I’m beginning to think you’re right about there being no shorter syntax.

Comment: Got it, then I don't see any shorter way to write `//*[local-name()=$users]/*[local-name()=$user]`. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

For your XML, which is not in a namespace,

```
<Users>
  <User>Bob</User>
  <User>Stefania</User>
</Users>
```

this XPath,

```
//User
```

selects multiple nodes (elements, specifically) in a single XPath,

```
  <User>Bob</User>
  <User>Stefania</User>
```

as requested.

The construct, `*[local-name()='User']` is used to defeat namespaces, which isn't recommended.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085) if your XML is actually in a namespace.