# xpath: prefix must resolve to a namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube, xml-namespaces

Below is the XML snippet of an SSIS package; I'm trying to write an XPath query to find all "SELECT *" statements from the SSIS package.

I'm getting below error

```
ERROR: Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: SQLTask
```

XML:

```
    <DTS:Executable
      DTS:refId="Package\TEST\TEST_COUNT"
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <SQLTask:SqlTaskData
          SQLTask:Connection="{F7343EC3-A89E-4236-962C-FD2EB8B9491E}"
          SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="select * from dbo.TEST where colname1=? and colname2=?"
          SQLTask:ResultType="ResultSetType_SingleRow" xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask">
        </SQLTask:SqlTaskData>
      </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:Executable>
```

Xpath query:

```
//SQLTask:SqlTaskData[contains(translate(@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,"select *")]/../../@DTS:refId
```

I was able to evaluate the xpath expression successfully from https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. However the actual packages are validated through XPath rules defined in SonarQube from where I'm getting this error.

Comment: You are using the `SQLTask:` prefix without declaring it. In other words, the error message means that SonarQube has no idea which namespace this prefix refers to. Search how to declare XML namespaces in SonarQube.

Comment: @Tomalak but the same expression worked when I uploaded the xml file in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: This might be, but freeformatter and SonarQube are not the same thing.

Comment: There's no mention of XML namespace support in [SonarQube's documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath), so if you cannot fix your XML to make it [***namespace-well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), you may have to use `local-name()` to [defeat namespaces in XPath as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085).

Comment: Could you figure it out or do you still need an answer?

Comment: @wp78de Couldn't figure out.. Moreover I'm just a beginner with Xpath. Appreciate support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your XPath query with skirted namespaces as pointed out in comments:

```
//*:SqlTaskData[contains(translate(@*:SqlStatementSource,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,"select *")]/../../@*:refId
```

For an explanation, read [kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes) excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/8291949).

Now, getting all SqlStatementSource that contain "select *" works the same way:

```
//*:SqlTaskData[contains(translate(@*:SqlStatementSource,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,"select *")]/@*:SqlStatementSource
```

**[Online Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3CDTS%3AExecutable%0A%20%20DTS%3ArefId%3D%22Package%5CTEST%5CTEST_COUNT%22%3E%0A%20%20%3CDTS%3AObjectData%3E%0A%20%20%3CSQLTask%3ASqlTaskData%0A%20%20%20%20SQLTask%3AConnection%3D%22%7BF7343EC3-A89E-4236-962C-FD2EB8B9491E%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20SQLTask%3ASqlStatementSource%3D%22select%20*%20from%20dbo.TEST%20where%20colname1%3D%3F%20and%20colname2%3D%3F%22%0A%20%20%20%20SQLTask%3AResultType%3D%22ResultSetType_SingleRow%22%20xmlns%3ASQLTask%3D%22www.microsoft.com%2Fsqlserver%2Fdts%2Ftasks%2Fsqltask%22%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FSQLTask%3ASqlTaskData%3E%0A%3C%2FDTS%3AObjectData%3E%0A%3C%2FDTS%3AExecutable%3E&=&extract=%2F%2F*%3ASqlTaskData%5Bcontains(translate(%40*%3ASqlStatementSource%2C'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'%2C%20'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')%20%2C%22select%20*%22)%5D%2F%40*%3ASqlStatementSource%0A&=%2F%2F*%3ASqlTaskData%5Bcontains(translate(%40*%3ASqlStatementSource%2C'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'%2C%20'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')%20%2C%22select%20*%22)%5D%2F%40*%3ASqlStatementSource&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)**

or use the `local-name()` function as you already found out:

```
 //*[local-name()='SqlTaskData'][contains(translate(@*[local-name()='SqlStatementSource'],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,"select count(*)")]/@*[local-name()='SqlStatementSource']
```

Comment: I tried this expression, it is working freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html & also in the online demo link you shared, but when I executed sonar scanner, it's still throwing error: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: ERROR: Caused by: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: Could it be something to do at SonarQube admin level?

Comment: I replaced the attributes in the expression with local-name() function and it worked
//*[local-name()='SqlTaskData'][contains(translate(@*[local-name()='SqlStatementSource'],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ,"select count(*)")]/@*[local-name()='SqlStatementSource'] . However now the sonarqube showing "There is a pending analysis. More details available on the Background Tasks page" :D

Comment: Can you put your solution as Answer, I can mark it correct and close the question. Anyway the thing worked.. Thank you very much :)