# XPath for attribute value based on another attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

Please help me to get an XML value using XPath.
I have following XML code:

```
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" name="Display Message" visibility="public" isReadOnly="false"/>
<packagedElement xmi:type='uml:Package' xmi:id='EAPK_358475EC_46AD_43eb_A00F_1A18E1B280D4' name='ATM Withdrawal'>
<node isReadOnly="false" name="Accept card" xmi:type="uml:Activity">
<ownedMember name="Model" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Package">
```

All I want is to get all `@name` value where `xmi:type="uml:Activity"`.
The results should be:

```
Display Message, Accept Card
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[@xmi:type="uml:Activity"]/@name
```

will select the `name` attributes for all elements with `@xmi:type="uml:Activity"`.

Note that this presumes that you've bound the `xmi` namespace prefix to match its binding in the XML document.  How you do that depends upon the language hosting XPath.  For details, see [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

Comment: Thank you. but how do I get the value from '<node>' element? '<node>' element has attribute '@xmi:type='uml:Activity' too

Comment: Answer updated to disregard element name so that both `packagedElement` and `node` (and any other element) will match.

Comment: Great! it helps. Thanks!