# XPATH: Parse XML need sibling's children and more

Tags: xml, xpath

so I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <realmCode code="US" />
  <typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" />
  <templateId root="1.2.840.114350.1.72.1.51693" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1" extension="2015-08-01" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" extension="2015-08-01" />
  <id assigningAuthorityName="EPC" root="1.2.840.114350.1.13.535.2.7.8.688883.17473398" />
  <code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of Episode Note" />
  <title>Clinical Summary</title>
  <effectiveTime value="20181016153816-0400" />
  <confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" displayName="Normal" />
  <languageCode code="en-US" />
  <setId assigningAuthorityName="EPC" extension="d5ccd6e6-4b6b-11e7-90e8-f508dff85edf" root="1.2.840.114350.1.13.535.2.7.1.1" />
  <versionNumber value="31" />
  <recordTarget>
```

This part is down lower, where I need to extract the data I need

```
          <code code="10160-0" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="History of Medication Usage" />
          <title>Current Medications</title>
          <text>
             <table>
                <colgroup>
                   <col width="25%" />
                   <col width="25%" />
                   <col width="13%" />
                   <col width="12%" />
                   <col width="8%" />
                   <col width="8%" />
                   <col width="9%" />
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                   <tr>
                      <th>Prescription</th>
                      <th>Sig.</th>
                      <th>Disp.</th>
                      <th>Refills</th>
                      <th>Start Date</th>
                      <th>End Date</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <tr ID="currx6">
                      <td>
                         <paragraph ID="med6">Misc. Devices (BATH/SHOWER SEAT) Misc</paragraph>
                         <content styleCode="allIndent">
                            Indications:
                            <content ID="indication7">Mild cognitive impairment</content>
                            ,
                            <content ID="indication8">MGD (meibomian gland disease)</content>
                            ,
                            <content ID="indication9">Glaucoma suspect</content>
                            ,
                            <content ID="indication10">Nuclear sclerosis</content>
                         </content>
                      </td>
                      <td ID="sig6">Pt needs shower/bath bar to assist with getting in and out of bath tub/shower.</td>
                      <td>
                         <paragraph>1 Units</paragraph>
                      </td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>06/21/2013</td>
                      <td />
                      <td>Active</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr ID="currx11">
                      <td>
                         <paragraph ID="med11">Misc. Devices (HUGO ROLLING WALKER) Misc</paragraph>
```

I'm pretty much trying to get the paragraph ones with the ID only. I was using this

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(  "//*[local-name()='code'][@code='10160-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']/table/tbody/tr/td/paragraph", new InputSource(new StringReader(docString)), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

but it keeps telling me I have 0 nodes... and if I make it just try to get the table it tells me I have 1 node.. but that its null.. what exactly am I doing wrong ??

SOLUTION : to get the paragraphs

```
//*[local-name()='code'][@code='10160-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']//*[local-name()='paragraph']
```

to get the ID= only ones

```
//*[local-name()='code'][@code='10160-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']//*[local-name()='paragraph'[@ID]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty much trying to get the paragraph ones with the ID only.

This XPath,

```
//*[@ID]
```

will select all elements that have an `ID` attribute, and this XPath,

```
//paragraph[@ID]
```

will select all paragraph elements that have an `ID` attribute.

**Other notes:**

- Don't use constructs such as `//*[local-name()='code']` when no namespaces are in play; just use `//code`.  (And if namespaces are in play, define a namespace prefix and reference them properly rather than defeating them.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085))
- `//*[local-name()='code'][@code='10160-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']` is failing because `text` isn't a sibling of `node`.  Perhaps you meant to use `following::` instead.

Comment: maybe I need to explain better.. I need to open xml file, find all with <code code="10160-0" parent nodes.. then get all of the nodes that have <paragraph ID= nodes under that parent... I can get all <paragraph> ones and weed out the ones I dont if needed.  I'll give what you said a try now

Comment: In your posted XML, `code` has no descendant elements at all; it's empty.

Comment: my indenting was hand done.. so  code,title and text are all siblings. So I assume I grab the code with the code # I want.. and then the following-sibling gets the text node. Then what I need to do is get the paragraph ones way under that.. make sense ?

Comment: Please fix your XML to be well-formed, without any `+` and `-` outline symbols.  Well-formed XML has a single root element.  Then you can use basic tools to handle the indentation for you.  Otherwise, you're wasting everyone's time on unnecessary distractions.  After you've done that, we'll be able to show you how to write an XPath to any node you need.

Comment: sorry about that.. whats the best way to get it indented automatically ? I just copied from IE window..but when you paste it.. it messes it all up

Comment: View the source.  Copy from there, not from the outline presentation.

Comment: You still haven't posted well-formed XML.  Without the root element of the XML, we don't know if there are namespaces in play.

Comment: here is the top of the XML

Comment: I think we got it..  //*[local-name()='code'][@code='10160-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']//*[local-name()='paragraph']