# How to use xpath to get a specific xsd element?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I am trying to find a specific xsd element of specific parent xsd elements 
using xpath but could not find a solution.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="XYZ">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="XX" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AA">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="testA" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="testB" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="YY" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="ZZ">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AA" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I tried the following xpath:

```
/xs:element[@name='XYZ']/xs:element[@name='XX']/xs:element[@name='AA']
```

but the result is an empty list.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: please add the actual xsd data on which you apply the xpath expression.

Comment: What hosting language are you using to execute the XPath, and how did you account for the XSD namespace?

Comment: Ich verwende die javax#XpathFactory. I am just trying to find a specific element from a given treeitemlist (XYZ, XX, AA). Sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: Do you understand how to use XML namespaces?

Comment: Maybe not good enough. So your answer is that i should look into xml namespaces again? Or that it is not possible to have two elements with the same name ('AA').

Comment: You have `xs:complexType` and `xs:sequence` elements between your `xs:element`...

Comment: Okay the problem is i can Not use the real xsd. So i prepared this quick example. My Hope was that this is enough to Show what i would Like to achieve with the xpath Statement: to get the right AA element by using the name Attributes of the Elements.

Comment: Yes, I'm guiding you to be sure you understand [how XPath deals with XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085).   Be sure to mind @Alejandro's point too.

Comment: `//xs:element[@name="XYZ"]//xs:element[@name="XX"]//xs:element[@name="AA"]` should give the desired result - you just need to use `//` to handle arbitrary depth of ancestors. [XPath Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is an indispensable guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//xs:element[@name="XYZ"]//xs:element[@name="XX"]//xs:element[@name="AA"]
```

should give the desired result - you just need to use `//` to handle arbitrary depth of ancestors.

From [XPath Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

---

```
bookstore//title
```

All `<title>` elements one or more levels deep in the `<bookstore>` element (arbitrary descendants).

---

```
bookstore//book/excerpt//emph
```

All `<emph>` elements anywhere inside `<excerpt>` children of `<book>` elements, anywhere inside the `<bookstore>` element.