# xpath query root element with the namespace

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath

I'm trying to address the root element with the namespace and providing a reference to the library [xml-crypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto).

I'm not giving the path correctly, please advise. Objective is to sign the document so the signature can be inserted right after the tag `<samlp:Response`

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="efedb3b0-909f-4b39-b8c0-57427ee8dc83" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-11-08T15:34:51.272Z">

    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://www.example.com</saml:Issuer>

</samlp:Response>
```

nodeJS code

```
var SignedXml = require('xml-crypto').SignedXml, fs = require('fs');
var sig = new SignedXml();

sig.addReference("//*[local-name(.)='samlp:Response']");

sig.signingKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/client.pem");
sig.computeSignature(xml);
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/signed.xml", sig.getSignedXml());
```

**Attempts**

```
sig.addReference("//samlp:Response");
```

> Error: Cannot resolve QName samlp

it worked fine at https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to defeat/bypass namespaces, then change

```
sig.addReference("//*[local-name(.)='samlp:Response']");
```

to

```
sig.addReference("//*[local-name()='Response']");
```

because the namespace prefix, `samlp`, is not part of the local name, `Response`.

For a comprehensive answer on namespaces in XPath, see [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)