# Reading XML tags with XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extrapolate a series of values ​​through XPath queries from XML files that I report here.

I state that I have little knowledge of the subject, so I apologize for inaccuracies in technical terminology.
After several attempts I managed to obtain some useful data for me such as those reported in the Idc-> FileGroup -> value node
with the query

```
//m:meta[2]/@value
```

which returns the different values ​​of the TAGs "value" based on the indexes 1,2,3 etc..

Despite repeated attempts, however, I was unable to create a query that allows me to obtain the value of the following TAGs: Idc-> FileGroup-> File s: format-> Path

which corresponds to `docs/002678E3.pdf` and from the TAG

> IdC -> SelfDescription-ID s;

scheme, which corresponds to

```
1520038843024
```

or, is the same for me,

```
"local">1520038843024
```

Could you please give me help?
This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IdC xmlns="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:s="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/ UNI1138600_2010_EIT.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd lotto.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd metadata.xsd">
  <SelfDescription>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1520038843024</ID>
    <CreatingApplication>
      <Name>tDoc</Name>
      <Version>r16610</Version>
      <Producer>Andxor Soluzioni Informatiche srl</Producer>
    </CreatingApplication>
    <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
      <EmbeddedMetadata>
        <lotto xmlns="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
          <company>SCOTT</company>
          <doctype>FATTURE_ATTIVE</doctype>
          <period>2018</period>
          <previous id="1519174898489">ED1C84CE3A825268E8434EFB80B9D09B4E0E9658F7A4D4FF5005CE6D10293388</previous>
        </lotto>
      </EmbeddedMetadata>
    </MoreInfo>
  </SelfDescription>
  <VdC>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1520038843024</ID>
  </VdC>
  <FileGroup xmlns:m="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2521309</ID>
      <Path>docs/002678DD.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">A041E222FC3F968EAED07405D9D8A32CD2A8BDB1952E8B726DDE3B7F55F20EE0</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2018-02-16T18:40:12+01:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Fattura" value="970081952"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2018-02-01"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA AUTOFATTURA CORRISPETT"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="140422"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2521315</ID>
      <Path>docs/002678E3.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">6FF865D8ECA154E31D9E362B12E11EA79CE04EB92EB558C7C0AAC32A5883156F</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2018-02-16T18:40:18+01:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Fattura" value="970081953"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2018-02-02"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA AUTOFATTURA CORRISPETT"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="140422"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2521321</ID>
      <Path>docs/002678E9.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">0F3755FA764DD00AA35D801908A4FEE9762C259CE18E2DC6BFAD50C49B013422</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2018-02-16T18:40:22+01:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Fattura" value="970081954"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2018-02-05"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA AUTOFATTURA CORRISPETT"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="140422"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2521335</ID>
      <Path>docs/002678F7.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">F3FE57B26F49065BCAEEC8B5B7DB58B8F9AE0E93ED692D8771D9116F5F6472C0</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2018-02-16T18:41:14+01:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Fattura" value="970081955"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2018-02-06"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA AUTOFATTURA CORRISPETT"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="140422"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
  </FileGroup>
  <Process>
    <Agent s:type="organization" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <FormalName>KPNQwest Italia SpA</FormalName>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">07957860153</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Giuseppe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Baccanelli</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">BCCGPP64C01A940D</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Giuseppe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Baccanelli</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">BCCGPP64C01A940D</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="organization" s:role="OtherRole" s:otherRole="Other role">
      <AgentName>
        <FormalName>Amministratore</FormalName>
      </AgentName>
    </Agent>
    <TimeReference>
      <TimeInfo>2018-03-03T02:00:43+01:00</TimeInfo>
    </TimeReference>
    <LawAndRegulations s:language="it">DPCM 3 dicembre 2013</LawAndRegulations>
  </Process>
</IdC>
```

Comment: A point about terminology: XPath does not read tags. Tags are either start tags (`<id>`) or end tags (`</id>`). The XML parser uses the tags to construct a tree of nodes; element nodes in the tree have names derived from the tags, but the tags themselves have gone by the time XPath searches the tree. XPath sees only named nodes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath-1.0 expressions you are looking for are probably

1. First: "to create a query that allows me to obtain the value of the following TAGs":

   > IdC -> FileGroup -> File s: format -> Path

   1. Simple

      ```
      /IdC/FileGroup/File[@s:format]/Path
      ```
   2. If you have to set the namespace explicitly, you can use

      ```
      /std:IdC/std:FileGroup/std:File[@s:format='application/pdf']/std:Path
      ```

      with the namespaces set to

      ```
      xmlns:std = "http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" 
      xmlns:s   = "http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/"
      ```
   3. Or, if you cannot set namespaces at all (due to whatever reason), use

      ```
      /*[local-name()='IdC']/*[local-name()='FileGroup']/*[local-name()='File'][@*[local-name()='format' and .='application/pdf']]/*[local-name()='Path']
      ```

   The result in all three cases is

   > docs/002678DD.pdf
2. To retrieve the value of

   > IdC -> SelfDescription -> ID

   use these XPath-1.0 expressions:

   1. With the above namespaces:

      ```
      /std:IdC/std:SelfDescription/std:ID
      ```
   2. Without the above namespaces:

      ```
      /*[local-name()='IdC']/*[local-name()='SelfDescription']/*[local-name()='ID']
      ```

   The result is in both cases:

   > 1520038843024

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you accounted for the default namespace on the root element?

Comment: Since XPath itself has no way to bind namespace prefixes to namespaces, consider referencing the canonical Q/A that covers how to do so for a multitude of languages and libraries when answering these sorts of questions: [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

Comment: FYI the OP tried to reply to you a day after you posted this answer, but he/she did so in an answer rather than a comment here. It is in a deleted answer on this page if you want to read/reply.

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for mentioning this. Indeed I haven't noticed the replies in the answers without any comment. (Changed some `name()` to `local-name()` just for completeness in relation to the root namespace issue)

Comment: No worries. You can always ping them with a comment under the question.