# xpath with default namespace with no preifx

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm using a library method for xpath evaluation  (apache `commons-text`'s `XmlStringLookup`) that sets the `DocumentBuilderFactory`'s namespace awareness to `true` and I can't change that. 
I need to query a `pom.xml` file with this, that has a default namespace with no prefix:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   ...
```

I would want to be able to query just like:

```
 /project/modelVersion
```

but because of the namespace awareness, the results come out empty. 
I know I can use something like :

```
//*[local-name()="project"] ...
```

but that's just cumbersome. 
The question is: is there any Xpath syntax to query namespaces without prefix? 
Something like:

```
/:project/:modelVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within XPath, no, there is no alternative syntax that ignores namespaces, default or otherwise, other than testing against `local-name()` (all versions) or `*:NCName` ([XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#node-tests) and later).

Within XPath, there also is no mechanism for binding namespace prefixes to namespaces.  For a list of namespace prefix binding mechanisms that are available in various hosting languages and libraries, see [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

Answer (score 1):

If you move to XPath 3.1 (as delivered through Saxon 10.0), then

(a) `/*:project` will retrieve an element with local name project, in any namespace (or none)

(b) `/Q{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project` will retrieve an element with local name project in the specified namespace, with no need to declare namespace prefixes externally

(c) The Saxon API allows you to call XPathCompiler.declareNamespace("", "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"), after which `/project` selects an element in this namespace.

Comment: I forgot about `*:projectname`.  Updated my answer.  Saxon supports it for XPath 2.0 (not just XPath 3.1) and up, no?

Comment: Yes, `*:local-name` was introduced in 2.0.