# XPath for hierarchical column / name-value properties?

Tags: xml, xpath, soa

I am trying to find the XPath of the below XML.  Its consists of properties array list. I need to fetch the value for 'COMPUTER'.

```
<output  xmlns:tns="http://www.ariuy.org/" custname="marcus" >
    <tns:column name="customer_english_name">marcus ag</tns:column>
    <tns:column name="customer_primary_name">marcus ag</tns:column>
   
    <tns:reqline>
        <tns:orderline user_item_description="xyz">
            <tns:column name="properties">
                <tns:column name="name">COMPUTER</tns:column>
                <tns:column name="value">HCL </tns:column>
            </tns:column>
            <tns:column name="properties">
                <tns:column name="name">LAPTOP</tns:column>
                <tns:column name="value">HP</tns:column>
            </tns:column>
            <tns:column name="properties">
                <tns:column name="name">PHONE</tns:column>
                <tns:column name="value">MI</tns:column>
            </tns:column>
            <tns:column name="properties">
                <tns:column name="name">JOB</tns:column>
                <tns:column name="value">Developer</tns:column>
            </tns:column>
            
            ......
       
        </tns:orderline>
    </tns:reqline>
</output>
```

I have tried

```
/tns:output/tns:reqline/tns:OrderLine/tns:properties[@name='COMPUTER']/@value
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What value exactly are you trying to fetch?

Answer (score 1):

To fecth `HCL`(value under `COMPUTER`), you can go with :

```
(//*[name()="tns:column"][@name="properties"])[1]/*[2]/text()
```

Look for the first column element with a specific attribute of the page. Then select its second child.

Or more secure option :

```
//*[name()="tns:column"][preceding-sibling::*[name()="tns:column"][.="COMPUTER"]]/text()
```

Look anywhere for a column element where its preceding-sibling contains the value "COMPUTER".

Comment: These answers are characteristic of a class of answers that can be shorter and more general (+1) than the one I posted, at the expense of efficiency, which won't matter at all for typical documents, but could for database dumps or other large documents.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the namespace prefix `tns` [properly declared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085) to abbreviate the `http://www.ariuy.org/` namespace value...

This XPath,

```
/output/tns:reqline/tns:orderline
  /tns:column[@name='properties'][tns:column[@name='name']='COMPUTER']
  /tns:column[@name='value']
```

will select

```
<tns:column name="value">HCL </tns:column>
```

as requested.

Comment: Downvoter:  Tell me what you think is wrong, and I'll fix or explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. but it return null value for me

Comment: Then you've made a mistake, likely related to namespace prefix declarations.  See the provided link to correct that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

/tns:output/tns:reqline/tns:OrderLine/tns:properties[@name='COMPUTER']/@value

Well

(a) the `output` element is not in the tns namespace

(b) the `orderline` element starts with `o` not `O`

(c) you don't have an element called `tns:properties`

(d) there's no `@name` attribute whose value is `"COMPUTER"`

(e) there's no `@value` attribute anywhere.

That's a lot of errors for one line of code.

Others have given you working solutions, but I think it's important you understand why your attempt is wrong.

Comment: Well ....There is no element called properties but there is array of elements. I need to fetch value of computer

Comment: According to you what should be the path?

Comment: I started such a list mentally while fixing OP's XPath but lost track and decided it wasn't worth cycling back for so many egregious errors.  Interesting to see now that neither a list of errors to fix nor a working solution suits.

Comment: @Anurag, with a question like this I prefer to encourage you to solve the problem yourself rather than solving it for you. Sorry if I'm being a bit nanny-ish here, but I think it's a better use of my time.