# Puppeteer find svg use xlink:href

Tags: html, xml, svg, xpath, puppeteer

I have the following html:

```
<button data-testid="likeButton">
    <svg aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/logo"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>Like</span>
</button>
```

Now the `<use xlink:href` could be either `/logo` or `/logo-filled`

How can I write an xpath expression in Puppeteer to get these?

I have tried this:

```
//*[name()='use'][contains(@*='logo')]
```

But when I test it, i get the error:

```
Unable to perform XPath operation. The prefix "xlink" for attribute "xlink:href" associated with an element type "use" is not bound.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
//*[name()='use'][contains(@*='logo')]
                             ^
```

to

```
//*[name()='use'][contains(@*,'logo')]
                             ^
```

or

```
//use[starts-with(@*,'/logo')]
```

but regarding namespaces, see also [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)