# XPath for namespaced XML attributes in Power Automate?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, power-automate

I receive an XML file by email each day, and am trying to write a Flow / Power Automate to parse the XML, get 3 variables from it, and append these to a table in Excel. The XML file has below structure, its loaded into the query with the identifier `InputXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ifir:inter_fund_investor_report ifir:creation_date_time="2021-02-24T21:16:01"
                                 ifir:report_id="102068045"
                                 xmlns:ifir="nzl:org:fsc:XMLSchema:InterfundInvestorReport:v2.0">
  <investor ifir:investor_name="client name" ifir:investor_id="client123">
    <fund ifir:currency="USD" ifir:fund_valuation_date="2021-02-23" ifir:fund_name="Fund Name" ifir:fund_id="fundcode" ifir:is_fund_a_PIE="Y">      
      <balances>        
        <investor_units_held>123456</investor_units_held>
        <total_units_on_issue>999999999</total_units_on_issue>
      </balances>
      <prices>
        <base_price>1.060</base_price>
        <entry_price>1.0650</entry_price>
        <exit_price>1.055</exit_price>
      </prices>
      <totals ifir:fund_allocation_date="2021-02-23"/>
    </fund>
  </investor>
</ifir:inter_fund_investor_report>
```

I have been able to get the `base_price` by using the expression:

```
xpath(xml(outputs('InputXML')),'//base_price')
```

I cannot however get the `fund_name` or the `fund_valuation_date` out from the XML.

Is someone able to help me with the XPath expression to get these two?
The XML file currently only has one `fund_name` but could in the future have more, so I should also make the `base_price` query conditional on that fund name if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no indication in the [Power Automate documentation for XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/xml) that it supports XPath querying of namespaced XML components.

You could work-around such a limitation by testing the local name of the attribute:

```
//fund[@*[local-name()='fund_name' and .='Fund Name']]/prices/base_price
```

This selects all `base_price` element children of `prices` element children of those `fund` elements whose `fund_name` attribute value is `'Fund Name'`, regardless of the namespace on the `fund_name` attribute.

### See also

- [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)