# XPath to reference an attribute by value?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I need to extract a series of values ​​through XPath queries from XML files that I report at end of the page.

In particular, I'm trying to find a query that allows me to select the values ​​related to the attributes, using the naming of the attributes themselves.

I am able through the following query, to read the values ​​of the first, second, third attribute etc..

```
 //m:meta[15]/@value
```

The problem is that in the XML file these positions can change, so I don't always get the desired values.

For example, I need the data always referring to the `"Ragione Sociale Destinatario"` attribute, but sometimes it occupies position 15 and sometimes position 16.

The query I am looking for is something like

```
//m:meta[name='Ragione Sociale Destinatario']
```

that must get the data written in the "connected" values ​​attribute.
To be clear, for the first element is `SIEM SPA`, for the second is `DML spa`, etc.

Could you kindly help me by giving me an example of the correct syntax?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IdC xmlns="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:s="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/ UNI1138600_2010_EIT.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd lotto.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd metadata.xsd">
  <SelfDescription>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1610960618898</ID>
    <CreatingApplication>
      <Name>tDoc</Name>
      <Version>r27212</Version>
      <Producer>Andxor Soluzioni Informatiche srl</Producer>
    </CreatingApplication>
    <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
      <EmbeddedMetadata>
        <lotto xmlns="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
          <company>IT08767050969</company>
          <doctype>FattureEmesse</doctype>
          <period>2020</period>
          <previous id="1610790947210">DDFCC019EEA10ECCCF4FC64E2D499CA3D757D6CC31523EB0813FE96F08694277</previous>
        </lotto>
      </EmbeddedMetadata>
    </MoreInfo>
  </SelfDescription>
  <VdC>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1610960618898</ID>
  </VdC>
  <FileGroup xmlns:m="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487958</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927031.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">F3D97E78EAC886325E755851E5BAE0E5702A1712ED7B83DFEF5F5FFE66899F04</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:21+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15065"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927031"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015065"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="05660991000"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fiscale Destinatario" value="01017000710"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="SIEM SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="siemspa_raccomandate@corporate.mailcert.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523569"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022540"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022551"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:16.290Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487962</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927071.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">F0C2B4F3B5143AD145EF6FD446FCFEF0A6AD9526B3A88E6A7026089AEC728D4F</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:21+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15078"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927071"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015078"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523575"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022541"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022549"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:06.930Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487966</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927161.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">BC4112D34259D10467DA3E93A52CD637B59C1EB73C1CE762329A5C98AFD253CE</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:22+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15080"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927161"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015080"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523580"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022541"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022548"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:05.336Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281488042</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927171.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">9C7F0AD4C559BF5CFD18672F7310C2309E636B360373036CB78BCC405D581A3B</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:29+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15079"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927171"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015079"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523592"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022542"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022550"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:10.305Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487977</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927191.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">BA56F93F1BAF60D85EF75130721CEDC4E3C565330873B7808EA3C774F99DEC5F</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:23+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15081"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927191"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015081"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523608"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022543"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022550"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:08.446Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487970</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927201.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">59A4A56D6CD479F4D6351BA4AB366FADC0F92647D4FC3AC958164D3065D138EF</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:22+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15085"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927201"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015085"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523613"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022543"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022550"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:09.462Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487974</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927231.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">B53BA8DF0CA160EC7C0FB345252E93B7170D88A89B94655A6D2259C38A259B7D</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:23+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15084"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927231"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015084"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523628"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022544"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022551"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:15.743Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281487981</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927241.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">A252324E8FD4B9657641E4E1F6DF880F49ECE3AF8FB892B9884F617FBF221CAF</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:23+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15082"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927241"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015082"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523636"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022544"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022549"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:06.508Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281488015</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927271.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">DBF2D582EC2F15AAA9D25042115E915468F1CE72EA19D0DC7173ACF2586EEF96</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:27+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15083"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927271"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015083"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523641"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022545"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022605"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:32.118Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="text/xml">
      <ID s:scheme="local">281488027</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054927301.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">4A092D16A954F6F43A284EA6F7B4F7D536B482557810AE54A3EA8B4A960DD17F</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:28+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15072"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054927301"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015072"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="02106250398"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="DML SPA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="HHBD9AK"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="Sede.dml-italia@legpec.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237523662"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022546"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022604"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:29.618Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>

      <ID s:scheme="local">281488232</ID>
      <Path>docs/23054929031.xml</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">96DF0E38DB51D5D6637CDAFFC9E8E585D6308EC8D16A4F71C690BAD0837888F1</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2020-12-18T18:22:47+01:00"/>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="PdV" value="w3JpQzRYzt7"/>
            <m:meta name="Controllo Sequenza" value="15116"/>
            <m:meta name="Tipo Postalizzazione" value="Fattura Elettronica B2B"/>
            <m:meta name="Notifica Ricevuta Consegna" value="Ricevuta Consegna"/>
            <m:meta name="Esito Processo" value="OK"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Documento" value="18-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ricevuta Consegna" value="19-12-2020"/>
            <m:meta name="ID Univoco" value="23054929031"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Documento" value="FV-202015116"/>
            <m:meta name="Sezionale" value="2020"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Mittente" value="08767050969"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Mittente" value="BIGBEN INTERACTIVE SRL"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita IVA Destinatario" value="08973230967"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario" value="AMAZON EU SARL, SUCCURSALE ITALIANA"/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Fatturazione Elettronica" value="XR6XN0E"/>
            <m:meta name="Indirizzo PEC" value="amazoneu@legalmail.it"/>
            <m:meta name="Identificativo SDI" value="4237524523"/>
            <m:meta name="Data Ora Ricezione" value="20201219022631"/>
            <m:meta name="Ora Ricevuta Consegna" value="022652"/>
            <m:meta name="Ultima Modifica" value="2020-12-19T02:28:54.463Z"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
  </FileGroup>
  <Process>
    <Agent s:type="organization" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <FormalName>TESI SpA (Responsabile Conservazione)</FormalName>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">02448510046</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Giuseppe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Crivello</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">CRVGPP69B20B791G</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="OtherRole" s:otherRole="Altro ruolo">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Amministratore</FirstName>
          <LastName>root</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode"></Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <TimeReference>
      <TimeInfo>2021-01-18T10:03:38+01:00</TimeInfo>
    </TimeReference>
    <LawAndRegulations s:language="it">DPCM 3 dicembre 2013</LawAndRegulations>
  </Process>
</IdC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, attributes are specified with a leading `@` character.

Also, XPath operates on well-formed XML documents.  Yours is not: The last `File` element is missing its start tag.

So, once you repair your XML, this XPath,

```
//m:meta[@name="Ragione Sociale Destinatario"]/@value
```

will return the `value` attributes for the `m:meta` elements whose `name` attribute is `"Ragione Sociale Destinatario"`, regardless of position, as requested.

Note that you will also have to define the binding between the `m` namespace prefix and its associated namespace URI.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

Comment: Thank you, the query written in this way works perfectly.
I realize, however, that I have another problem: can I get only the desired number of values ​​from the query?
For example, I only want the first 10 values ​​of the Ragione Sociale.
I tried with the "position" function but obviously I am wrong in compiling the query, for example:

// m: meta [@ name = "Recipient Company Name"] [position ()> 1and position () <= 10] / @ value

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work
Would you be kind enough to give me another suggestion?

Thanks again

Comment: If you follow the instructions regarding repair of the malformed XML and the namespace prefix declaration, the answer will indeed work as described.  If you're having trouble, update your question with (1) a [mcve] illustrating the issue and (2) details regarding what XPath hosting language/systems you're using and how you're doing the namespace prefix binding.

Comment: Regarding your position-related follow-up:  That's an entirely different topic and thus requires an entirely new question.

Comment: I understand, just a clarification: I confirm that the query works so your answer is correct.

The problem only concerns the extraction of a defined number of values, I will definitely follow the suggestion to put the question in another topic

Thanks