# How can I access an xpath with a colon in the name?

Tags: xpath, escaping, character, special-characters

I am trying to access the contents of the path below:

```
/newsMessage/itemSet/newsItem[2]/contentSet/remoteContent[3]/rtr:altId
```

However, the path is not being accepted due to the colon, is there any way to escape this character or make the contents of this path accessible.

I have tried using something similar to this:

```
/*[name()='rtr:altId']
```

however I'm unsure where I would put this in the CSS and if I have formatted correctly.

Comment: You will find many posts on this subject. You need to declare the prefix used in your XPath expression from the calling API, and the details depend on what XPath API you are using, which you haven't told us. I linked to an answer relevant to PHP, but you will find the same question asked for many other APIs and the answer is usually very similar.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Since OP didn't mention a language, I've changed the PHP-based duplicate link to the canonical answer I wrote to [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085) -- it covers nearly all languages/APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/newsMessage/itemSet/newsItem[2]/contentSet/remoteContent[3]/*[name()="altId"]
```

or

```
/newsMessage/itemSet/newsItem[2]/contentSet/remoteContent[3]/*[local-name()="altId"]
```