# XPath that returns true when at least one element matches

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Let's assume we have the following XML response:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Age>29</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Age>18</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Age>45</Age>
    </Person>
</People>
```

I want an xpath 2.0 expression that will return true if there is at least one person with age between 18 and 22.

My current expression is:

```
boolean(//*:Person[xs:integer(substring(//*[local-name() = 'Age']/text(), 2)) >= 18 and 22 >= xs:integer(substring(//*[local-name() = 'Age']/text(), 2))])
```

But this expression is not recursive so it produces the following error:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring() ("29", "25", ...)

Any idea as to how I can achieve what I need?

Comment: You should always say which version of XPath you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 this is `exists(//Person[Age = (18 to 22)])`

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using, so I will accept it as answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
boolean(/People/Person[Age > 18][Age < 22])
```

will return true iff at least one `Person` has an age between 18 and 22, exclusive.

**Notes:**

- Be sure to use `&lt;` for `<` if this XPath is embedded in XML/XSLT.
- Use `>=` and/or `<=` for inclusive endpoints.
- There is no reason to use `local-name()` and `*:` unless you are trying to defeat namespaces, which

  1. are not in play here anyway, but
  2. [can and should be accommodated, not defeated.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

Comment: you could also use: `boolean(/People/Person[Age[ . > 18 and . < 22]])`

Comment: Or `count(/People/Person[Age[ . > 18 and . < 22]]) > 0` ;-)

Comment: I have simplified my example by changing data structure to something more understandable and also removing namespaces. I should have also removed local-name() for this example, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

here's a twisted one that uses `count` and `translate`

`count(//Age[translate(translate(., "1", "X"),"89","YY") = "XY" or .="22" or translate(translate(., "2", "X"),"01","YY") = "XY"]) > 0`

`22` is an special case since `translate` turns it into `XX`