# XPath with namespace in query tool tab

Tags: xpath, xmlspy

I am trying to use the XPath query tool (bottom tab in XMLSpy) to test XPaths in an XML that uses namespaces.

I don't know how to declare the namespace.

Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Data xmlns="http://www.myns.com">
            <Text>test</Text>
        </Data>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
```

If I select XQuery 3.1 as my query language, I can test my XPath like this:

```
declare namespace myns="http://www.myns.com";
//Level1/Level2/myns:Data
```

But if I select XPath 3.1 as my query language, how do I define the namespace?
(Doing simply *//Level1/Level2/Data* does not work.)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about XMLSpy, better ask the Altova support whether/how to bind a prefix for XPath evaluation. The only pure XPath 3 solution is to use steps with the URI of the namespace included e.g. `/Level1/Level2/Q{http://www.myns.com}Data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XPath 1.0** (and higher)

```
//Level1/Level2/*[local-name()='Data']
```

or

```
//Level1/Level2/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.myns.com' and local-name()='Data']
```

**XPath 2.0** (and higher)

```
//Level1/Level2/*:Data
```

**XPath 3.0 or 3.1**

```
//Level1/Level2/Q{http://www.myns.com}Data
```

See also [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/3710053)

Comment: Thanks, this would indeed work, but I would have liked to reference the actual namepace used.

Comment: Just added two more options

Comment: Your second 2.0 example should really be another 1.0 example (there’s nothing 2.0 specific about it). You could have a second 2.0 example like this: `//Level1/Level2/*:Data[namespace-uri()='http://www.myns.com']`

Comment: I will accept this answer as I have contacted Altova and there is no way to declare a namespace in the XPath tab, as what can be done in XQuery. They refered me to this for examples : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-use-xpath-namespaces-rit